# How to populate SQL Server database with list of list of objects instead of looping

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have data coming from an Excel spreadsheet, I cannot change how this comes in. Is there a solution for adding `IList<IList<Object>>` values to a SQL Server database instead of looping as I am reaching limit with currently 5k rows.

I was also informed that I shouldn't use injection, so any alternatives are welcomed.

```
public static void Load_Table()
{
    // This function on_click populates the datagrid named JumpTable
    // this.JumpTable.ItemsSource = null; // Clears the current datagrid before getting new data
    // Pulls in the 2d table from the client sheet
    IList<IList<Object>> client_sheet = Get(SetCredentials(), "$placeholder", "Client!A2:AY");
    DBFunctions db = new DBFunctions();
    db.postDBTable("DELETE FROM Client");

    foreach (var row in client_sheet)
    {
        string exe = "INSERT INTO Client ([Tracker ID],[Request ID]) VALUES('" + row[0].ToString() + "','" + row[1].ToString() + "')";
        db.postDBTable(exe);
    }
}
```

Database functions

```
public SqlConnection getDBConnection()
{
    // --------------< Function: Opens the connection to our database >-------------- \\
    string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.connection_string; // Gets the connection source from properties
    SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString); // Creates the connection based off our source
    if (dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open) dbConnection.Open(); // If it's not already open then open the connection

    return dbConnection;
}
public DataTable getDBTable(string sqlText)
{
    // --------------< Function: Gets the table from our database >-------------- \\
    SqlConnection dbConnection = getDBConnection();

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlText, dbConnection);adapter.Fill(table);

    return table;
}

public void postDBTable(string sqlText)
{
    // --------------< Function: Post data to our database >-------------- \\
    SqlConnection dbConnection = getDBConnection();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, dbConnection);cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Before anything, you should really be fixing that injection problem. You need to parametrise those queries.

Comment: parametrise? I was going off of a tutorial that used this method, could you explain.

Comment: "*Bind list of list of objects to sql server database*"? What exactly do you mean by this? You don't "bind" anything to a database.

Comment: Understood, updated.

Comment: [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) @ChristopherBradley . If the tutorial is "recommending" you inject valeus int your queries, my honest opinion is you find a different (and better) tutorial.

Comment: @Larnu ok I will, but could you briefly explain why injecting is bad? I have no experience with sql and am learning it now.

Comment: [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: If you need to import data from an Excel spreadsheet to a SQL Server table, you should use SSIS.  That's what it was **made** for.

Comment: @Brian while SSIS was built and designed for this, there are some scenarios where I could see SSIS being a bad fit.

Comment: Perhaps, @RubberChickenLeader, but this is not one of them.  Based on the code in the initial question, this seems like a **perfect** fit for SSIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with lots of bulk data loads in the past.  There are two main ways to avoid individual inserts with SQL Server, a list of values inserted at one time or using bulk insert.

the first option to use a list of values is like this:

```
INSERT INTO Foo (Bar,Baz)
VALUES ('bar','baz'),
       ('anotherbar','anotherbaz')
```

In c# you would loop through your list and build the values content, however doing this with out a sql injection vulnerability is difficult.

The second option is to use bulk insert with SQL Bulk copy and a `datatable`.  Before getting to the code below you would build a `DataTable` that holds all your data then use `SqlBulkCopy` to insert rows using Sql functionality that is optimized for inserting large amounts of data.

```
using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con)
{
    //bulk mapping is a SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping[] and is not necessaraly needed if the DataTable matches your destination table exactly
    foreach (var i in bulkMapping)
    {
        bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(i);
    }

    bulk.DestinationTableName = "MyTable";

    bulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
    bulk.BatchSize = 5000;

    bulk.WriteToServer(someDataTable);
}
```

These are the two framework included methods.  There are other libraries that can help.  Dapper is one but I am not sure how it handles inserts on the back end.  Entity framework is another but it does single inserts so it is just moving the problem from your code to some one else's.

Comment: Your second option was a valid solution, I will also explore SSIS it seems like there are differences of opinions on this subject.